# object serialization - issue

Tags: php, php-5.3

Please have a look at below given code.

```
class Connection
{
    protected $link;
    private $server, $username, $password, $db, $cnt;

    public function __construct($server, $username, $password, $db)
    {
        $this->server = $server;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->cnt = 1;
        $this->connect();
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        echo '<br /> in connect '.($this->cnt++);
        $this->link = mysql_connect($this->server, $this->username, $this->password);
        mysql_select_db($this->db, $this->link);
    }

    public function __sleep()
    {
        echo '<br />in sleep';
        return array('server', 'username', 'password', 'db');
    }

    public function __wakeup()
    {
        echo '<br /> in wake up';
        $this->connect();
    }
}
$obj = new Connection('server', 'test', 'test', 'test');
$s = serialize($obj);
$obj->connect();
unserialize($s);
```

If i am not wrong then, Serialize should destroy all other members of class.

```
 $s = serialize($obj);
    $obj->connect();
    unserialize($s);
```

after serialize of 'server', 'username', 'password', 'db' properties 'cnt' should destroy. but when i call $obj->connect(); it gives me $this->cnt  value ....

Plz explain

Comment: why after serialize of 'server', 'username', 'password', 'db' properties 'cnt' should destroy? All of these will be destroyed?

Comment: yes...but when u call connect after serialize it is still connect to db and ptint cnt as 2---it means variables are not destroyed...they are avilable

Answer (score 0):

serialize() handles all types, except the resource-type. Thus the returned resource from mysql_connect will not be serialized.